# multipart/form-data to azure blob

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, sendgrid

Currently parsing the multipart/form-data has been successful except for the images.

**The tech being used:**

NodeJS w/ Azure Function 2.0 (tried with both binary and stream datatypes)

Sendgrid Inbound Parser (https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook/#example-default-payload)

Azure Blob

I'm able to parse out the images using Buffer leading to the following format for the attachments

```
{ filename: 'cb.jpg',
       name: 'cb.jpg',
       type: 'image/jpeg',
       content:
        <Buffer 0d 0a ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 48 00 48 00 00 ff e2 0c 58 49 43 43 5f 50 52 4f 46 49 4c 45 00 01 01 00 00 0c 48 4c 69 6e 6f 02 10 ... > },
```

The buffer I try to feed into the azure blob as such

```
const blockBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, recordId + path.sep + attachment.filename);
var bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
bufferStream.end(Buffer.from(attachment.content.toString('base64')));

const aborter = Aborter.timeout(NINE_MINUTES);

return uploadStreamToBlockBlob(aborter, bufferStream, blockBlobURL, EIGHT_MEGABYTES, 5);
```

I've tried with and without the toString and the base64 but no luck. The file uploads but the content i'm sending over is malformed in some way when i try to view it in the storage blob. Any thoughts on what transformation steps i'm missing?

Comment: Could you please tell me error and tell me if you can directly convert the buffer to image?

Comment: Hey @JimXu no error, just when i download the file and try to open it, it says its not a real jpg.

Can you expand on the converting the buffer to image suggestion?

Comment: According to my understanding, you can successfully upload the image to Azure blob but you cannot download the image from blob. Right? If so, could you please provide your download code?

Comment: Sort of, I can upload the buffer to the blob. But when i inspect the image uploaded (by downloading it and trying to open in my browser) it shows that the buffer i uploaded is malformed

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, we can use the following code:

```
 const fs = require('fs')
    const {
      Aborter,
      BlobURL,
      BlockBlobURL,
      ContainerURL,
      ServiceURL,
      StorageURL,
      SharedKeyCredential,
      uploadStreamToBlockBlob,
    } = require('@azure/storage-blob');

    const stream = require('stream');
    const ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
    const uploadOptions = { bufferSize: 4 * ONE_MEGABYTE, maxBuffers: 20 };
    const ONE_MINUTE = 60 * 1000;
    const aborter = Aborter.timeout(30 * ONE_MINUTE);;
    const accountname ="blobstorage0516";
    const key = "";
    const containerName="test";
    const sharedKeyCredential = new SharedKeyCredential(
      accountname,
      key);
    const pipeline = StorageURL.newPipeline(sharedKeyCredential);
    const serviceURL = new ServiceURL(
      `https://${accountname}.blob.core.windows.net`,
      pipeline
    );
    async function upload() {




      console.log("----")
      // read jpg to buffer
      const str = fs.readFileSync("D:\\test.jpg")

       //upload  
      const containerURL = ContainerURL.fromServiceURL(serviceURL, containerName);
      const blobURL = BlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, "test.jpg");
      const blockBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromBlobURL(blobURL);
      const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
      bufferStream.end(str);


        await uploadStreamToBlockBlob(aborter, bufferStream,
           blockBlobURL, uploadOptions.bufferSize, uploadOptions.maxBuffers);

        // download
        const baseLineImage = await blockBlobURL.download(aborter, 0)

         const datastream =  new stream.PassThrough();
    const readableStream = baseLineImage.readableStreamBody
    readableStream.on("data", data => {
      datastream.push(data);

    });
    readableStream.on("end" , () => {
      fs.writeFileSync('D:\\test1.jpg', datastream.read())
      console.log("download successfully")
      datastream.destroy();

  });
  readableStream.on("error" , (error) => {

    datastream.destroy();
    throw error;

});




    }

    upload()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Successfully executed sample.");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
```

[image]
[image]
[image]